# Running a parameter query within an Access form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, parameters

I have created forms that will allow the user to dictate the constraints of a query i.e. student attendance for their state versus another state with the use of ComboBoxes. The problem arises when I add multiple constraints to the query. I have had intermittent success with 2 categories but it seems only consistent with 1 category. I need three categories but I have had no success getting all three categories to work on the same form.  However, all categories work by themselves if run independently (removing some constraints from query). So, I know that the ComboBoxes on my form work properly. It seems the problem is with the query's SQL.

```
SELECT 
Students_All_Classes.LastName, Students_All_Classes.FirstName, 
    Students_All_Classes.[Class Name], Students_All_Classes.State, 
    Students_All_Classes.ClassDate
FROM Students_All_Classes
WHERE 
    (((Students_All_Classes.[Class Name])=[Forms]![User Input]![ComboClass])     AND 
    ((Students_All_Classes.State)=[Forms]![User Input]![ComboState]) AND 
    ((Students_All_Classes.ClassDate)=[Forms]![User Input]![ComboDate]));
```

I think the problem is with the AND operator in the where statement.  If I change it to OR I can use all three constraints. But, I need the constraints to be cumulative so it it catagory x AND category y AND category Z. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this SQL you're building in VBA or from a query's SQL view?  It might just want #s around the combo box with the date.  If you remove the date criteria, does it work correctly?

Comment: The query will execute and give results with 1 and sometimes 2 constraints.  If I attempt to have 3 three constraints (like I have written out in SQL above) the query does not execute. There is no error message but, no results are given - even though I know the items chosen should return results.

Comment: This is the SQL view. The problem child seems to be the Date variable.  How would I rewrite the SQL with #?

Comment: you just use # as a delimeter before and after your combo box with the date value- #[Forms]![User Input]![ComboDate]#.  It tells Access to treat the text value returned from the combo box as a date.

Comment: That gives a syntax error.

Comment: Are you positive there are record which _do_ in fact satisfy the 3 constraints?

Comment: Yes. I am choosing filters that I know go together. All data entries have the same columns - so, I chose one row and used its criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the combodata is a string as is:

```
SELECT 
Students_All_Classes.LastName, Students_All_Classes.FirstName, 
    Students_All_Classes.[Class Name], Students_All_Classes.State, 
    Students_All_Classes.ClassDate
FROM Students_All_Classes
WHERE 
    (((Students_All_Classes.[Class Name])=[Forms]![User Input]![ComboClass])     
    AND 
    ((Students_All_Classes.State)=[Forms]![User Input]![ComboState]) 
    AND 
    ((Students_All_Classes.ClassDate)=Format([Forms]![User Input]![ComboDate], "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")));
```